# pastebin api : invalid api_dev_key

Tags: python, request, pastebin

I'm trying to paste from my python script using following snippet:

```
import requests
API_ENDPOINT = "http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php"

data = {'api_dev_key':'my key',
        'api_option': 'paste',
        'api_paste_code': 'hola',
        'api_paste_expire_date':'10M'
}


r = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, data = data)
print(r)
print(r.text)
```

Which worked well after a few days, but now it returns bad request, invalid api_dev_key. I can't find
where is the problem and I tried with another account's key.

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Comment: Not yet, i checked my account, and I mailed pastebin admins, to know if I had a penalty.

Comment: You should try it on a new account maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the **HTTP** to **HTTPS**, i think that should do it!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine and works perfectly on mine too with my own `data`. Ensure that your account is active and has no warning for any verification.

You can simply try changing the `api_dev_key` to an acceptable value in pastebin.com.conf and see if it fixes the issue.

Lastly, as mentioned [here](http://192.184.83.59/SPG%20All/pastebin.com/api.html#1), try doing an `HTTPS` request, and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, pastebin was on maintenance, and only accepted https request